# Linked list starting with an empty list and sorting new numbers added to it in Java

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, linked-list, testcase

I'm trying to create a link list class in java that applies to my test cases but am having trouble succeeding, the first test case asks me to start with an empty list, use the addSorted(I element) method to add java.lang.Integer objects representing the odd numbers (1 ≤ n ≤ 9,999) to the list. So far I'm still lost in setting it up, does anyone know basic ways of setting up a link list? My code is below..

```
public class LinkedList<I extends Comparable<? super I>> implements ListInterface<I> {

    @Override
    public int size() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(I element) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(I element, int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void addSorted(I element) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }

    @Override
    public I get(int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public I replace(I element, int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void removeAll() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you need to create your LinkedList from scratch or you need to extend existing LinkedList and update it to pass you test?

Comment: Please show some effort. Having your IDE generate the skeleton is not considered effort. We're not here to do your homework.

Comment: @AlexeyOdintsov I'm implementing from an interface and using existing methods to pass specific tests

Comment: @Robert Sorry, I'm lost and not sure where to start with the methods I need to pass my test cases

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea to solve your problem. use **public class LinkedList extends Collections implements ListInterface {** instead of **public class LinkedList implements ListInterface {**. So now you got access to sort method of collections class which will sort in natural order for given data type. 
Now when u call the get method using index before checking for the element for given index sort the list you hold locally then return back desire index value.

```
@Override
public I get(int index) {
    Collections.sort(....);
    return null;
}
```